# An example of symmetric, real entry matrix with non-real eigenvalues, according to Mathematica. Is this a bug?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, debugging

The following matrix is symmetric and all entries are real,

```
In[147]:= mat == 0.5*(mat+ Transpose[mat])

In[153]:= Table[
 Select[mat[[i]], Not[Element[#1, Reals]] &], {i, 1, 30}]
```

Due to limitation of 30000 char, I don't show the results. The first is True, and 2nd all empty lists.

Here's the matrix.

```
{{4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.758846257005955*^306, 
  -6.607783593326043*^306, 
  4.5933074584793086*^306, 
  3.563944546335317*^306, 
  -6.265160288720216*^306, 
  4.35513770635784*^306, 
  3.524681398036245*^306, 
  -6.196138474734244*^306, 
  4.307158167000686*^306, 
  3.781304214412078*^306, 
  -6.647263080472186*^306, 
  4.620751066491604*^306, 
  3.51759808243552*^306, 
  -6.183686511176122*^306, 
  4.2985023603634954*^306, 
  4.0378293703075546*^306, 
  -7.098216006051991*^306, 
  4.934224624944834*^306, 
  3.356800284504563*^306, 
  -5.901015452462095*^306, 
  4.102007565407017*^306, 
  3.377816973501901*^306, 
  -5.93796129255433*^306, 
  4.1276899444466173*^306, 
  3.2897456023081654*^306, 
  -5.783138104313788*^306, 
  4.0200667913504564*^306}, 
 {-7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.607783593326043*^306, 
  1.161601220982305*^307, 
  -8.074706861625608*^306, 
  -6.265160288720216*^306, 
  1.1013704880374341*^307, 
  -7.656021426550555*^306, 
  -6.196138474734244*^306, 
  1.0892369454859652*^307, 
  -7.57167681884317*^306, 
  -6.647263080472186*^306, 
  1.1685414332070263*^307, 
  -8.12295076690035*^306, 
  -6.183686511176122*^306, 
  1.0870479791149493*^307, 
  -7.556460528212067*^306, 
  -7.098216006051991*^306, 
  1.247815740780918*^307, 
  -8.674014921926125*^306, 
  -5.901015452462095*^306, 
  1.0373564233457479*^307, 
  -7.211036695069822*^306, 
  -5.93796129255433*^306, 
  1.0438512384914352*^307, 
  -7.256184485442771*^306, 
  -5.783138104313788*^306, 
  1.0166344263854468*^307, 
  -7.066990659287911*^306}, 
 {5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.5933074584793086*^306, 
  -8.074706861625608*^306, 
  5.613018454478496*^306, 
  4.35513770635784*^306, 
  -7.656021426550555*^306, 
  5.3219751864106184*^306, 
  4.307158167000686*^306, 
  -7.57167681884317*^306, 
  5.2633442233663465*^306, 
  4.620751066491604*^306, 
  -8.12295076690035*^306, 
  5.646554523993312*^306, 
  4.2985023603634954*^306, 
  -7.556460528212067*^306, 
  5.252766833798561*^306, 
  4.934224624944834*^306, 
  -8.674014921926125*^306, 
  6.029618989956918*^306, 
  4.102007565407017*^306, 
  -7.211036695069822*^306, 
  5.012650333810375*^306, 
  4.1276899444466173*^306, 
  -7.256184485442771*^306, 
  5.044034182770469*^306, 
  4.0200667913504564*^306, 
  -7.066990659287911*^306, 
  4.912518766065072*^306}, 
 {3.758846257005955*^306, 
  -6.607783593326043*^306, 
  4.5933074584793086*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.887700554570214*^306, 
  -6.834300256993171*^306, 
  4.7507673186573794*^306, 
  3.8453182708785675*^306, 
  -6.759795225481607*^306, 
  4.6989761980640905*^306, 
  3.98516673397331*^306, 
  -7.005638847914138*^306, 
  4.8698709207180616*^306, 
  3.7732495312052806*^306, 
  -6.633103521952304*^306, 
  4.610908249329154*^306, 
  3.856803722207895*^306, 
  -6.779985829636917*^306, 
  4.713011411437522*^306, 
  3.539871810893023*^306, 
  -6.222842136972033*^306, 
  4.325720840731321*^306, 
  3.4701265213078897*^306, 
  -6.100234892961072*^306, 
  4.2404921463551987*^306, 
  3.3852889203129575*^306, 
  -5.951096442058326*^306, 
  4.1368206581470294*^306}, 
 {-6.607783593326043*^306, 
  1.161601220982305*^307, 
  -8.074706861625608*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.834300256993171*^306, 
  1.2014212346634932*^307, 
  -8.351510063872254*^306, 
  -6.759795225481607*^306, 
  1.188323781583981*^307, 
  -8.260464968239932*^306, 
  -7.005638847914138*^306, 
  1.2315413367528236*^307, 
  -8.560885700381923*^306, 
  -6.633103521952304*^306, 
  1.1660522838223707*^307, 
  -8.105647796437825*^306, 
  -6.779985829636917*^306, 
  1.191873145770615*^307, 
  -8.285137872188832*^306, 
  -6.222842136972033*^306, 
  1.0939312588244717*^307, 
  -7.604308675146666*^306, 
  -6.100234892961072*^306, 
  1.0723777799108683*^307, 
  -7.45448270997731*^306, 
  -5.951096442058326*^306, 
  1.0461603040784252*^307, 
  -7.272235628814887*^306}, 
 {4.5933074584793086*^306, 
  -8.074706861625608*^306, 
  5.613018454478496*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.7507673186573794*^306, 
  -8.351510063872254*^306, 
  5.80543429186982*^306, 
  4.6989761980640905*^306, 
  -8.260464968239932*^306, 
  5.742145579259999*^306, 
  4.8698709207180616*^306, 
  -8.560885700381923*^306, 
  5.950978809062406*^306, 
  4.610908249329154*^306, 
  -8.105647796437825*^306, 
  5.634526608406059*^306, 
  4.713011411437522*^306, 
  -8.285137872188832*^306, 
  5.759296600041806*^306, 
  4.325720840731321*^306, 
  -7.604308675146666*^306, 
  5.2860277974916044*^306, 
  4.2404921463551987*^306, 
  -7.45448270997731*^306, 
  5.181878393449171*^306, 
  4.1368206581470294*^306, 
  -7.272235628814887*^306, 
  5.0551919084324786*^306}, 
 {3.563944546335317*^306, 
  -6.265160288720216*^306, 
  4.35513770635784*^306, 
  3.887700554570214*^306, 
  -6.834300256993171*^306, 
  4.7507673186573794*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.7052413677982366*^306, 
  -6.513550021849522*^306, 
  4.527802321909851*^306, 
  3.9276657736932985*^306, 
  -6.904556261407554*^306, 
  4.79960478806323*^306, 
  4.0207837877598504*^306, 
  -7.06825108783075*^306, 
  4.9133949351684666*^306, 
  3.6262148204805167*^306, 
  -6.374626988796509*^306, 
  4.4312319371712406*^306, 
  3.7667170306425864*^306, 
  -6.621619851940232*^306, 
  4.602925538277533*^306, 
  3.6425108735207126*^306, 
  -6.403274287609083*^306, 
  4.45114570242136*^306, 
  3.567133553182516*^306, 
  -6.270766335278956*^306, 
  4.359034670461939*^306}, 
 {-6.265160288720216*^306, 
  1.1013704880374341*^307, 
  -7.656021426550555*^306, 
  -6.834300256993171*^306, 
  1.2014212346634932*^307, 
  -8.351510063872254*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.513550021849522*^306, 
  1.145035631304821*^307, 
  -7.95955350415708*^306, 
  -6.904556261407554*^306, 
  1.213771739088534*^307, 
  -8.437362851407276*^306, 
  -7.06825108783075*^306, 
  1.2425481219037526*^307, 
  -8.637397813125304*^306, 
  -6.374626988796509*^306, 
  1.1206139530616148*^307, 
  -7.789789656357341*^306, 
  -6.621619851940232*^306, 
  1.1640335365497068*^307, 
  -8.091614759832817*^306, 
  -6.403274287609083*^306, 
  1.125649943845596*^307, 
  -7.824796635175863*^306, 
  -6.270766335278956*^306, 
  1.1023559910333393*^307, 
  -7.662872011466831*^306}, 
 {4.35513770635784*^306, 
  -7.656021426550555*^306, 
  5.3219751864106184*^306, 
  4.7507673186573794*^306, 
  -8.351510063872254*^306, 
  5.80543429186982*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.527802321909851*^306, 
  -7.95955350415708*^306, 
  5.5329712240783717*^306, 
  4.79960478806323*^306, 
  -8.437362851407276*^306, 
  5.865113644824743*^306, 
  4.9133949351684666*^306, 
  -8.637397813125304*^306, 
  6.004165123832632*^306, 
  4.4312319371712406*^306, 
  -7.789789656357341*^306, 
  5.414962282461961*^306, 
  4.602925538277533*^306, 
  -8.091614759832817*^306, 
  5.624771741166156*^306, 
  4.45114570242136*^306, 
  -7.824796635175863*^306, 
  5.4392968894651854*^306, 
  4.359034670461939*^306, 
  -7.662872011466831*^306, 
  5.326737273780226*^306}, 
 {3.524681398036245*^306, 
  -6.196138474734244*^306, 
  4.307158167000686*^306, 
  3.8453182708785675*^306, 
  -6.759795225481607*^306, 
  4.6989761980640905*^306, 
  3.7052413677982366*^306, 
  -6.513550021849522*^306, 
  4.527802321909851*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.6799284697010196*^306, 
  -6.469051752617422*^306, 
  4.4968699783991354*^306, 
  3.571390908322127*^306, 
  -6.278250461928206*^306, 
  4.3642371554211796*^306, 
  3.6390574568563934*^306, 
  -6.39720342745276*^306, 
  4.446925629708386*^306, 
  3.346598331547328*^306, 
  -5.883081146890257*^306, 
  4.089540786133408*^306, 
  3.241824187980187*^306, 
  -5.69889567626151*^306, 
  3.9615068570505863*^306, 
  3.170464507445024*^306, 
  -5.573450448118335*^306, 
  3.8743053780792307*^306}, 
 {-6.196138474734244*^306, 
  1.0892369454859652*^307, 
  -7.57167681884317*^306, 
  -6.759795225481607*^306, 
  1.188323781583981*^307, 
  -8.260464968239932*^306, 
  -6.513550021849522*^306, 
  1.145035631304821*^307, 
  -7.95955350415708*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.469051752617422*^306, 
  1.1372131529894273*^307, 
  -7.905176650735032*^306, 
  -6.278250461928206*^306, 
  1.1036716471124116*^307, 
  -7.67201760892087*^306, 
  -6.39720342745276*^306, 
  1.1245827299348496*^307, 
  -7.817378048373208*^306, 
  -5.883081146890257*^306, 
  1.0342037003554311*^307, 
  -7.189120986388672*^306, 
  -5.69889567626151*^306, 
  1.001825208452996*^307, 
  -6.964046471993284*^306, 
  -5.573450448118335*^306, 
  9.797728321728929*^306, 
  -6.810752492228423*^306}, 
 {4.307158167000686*^306, 
  -7.57167681884317*^306, 
  5.2633442233663465*^306, 
  4.6989761980640905*^306, 
  -8.260464968239932*^306, 
  5.742145579259999*^306, 
  4.527802321909851*^306, 
  -7.95955350415708*^306, 
  5.5329712240783717*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.4968699783991354*^306, 
  -7.905176650735032*^306, 
  5.4951719222603755*^306, 
  4.3642371554211796*^306, 
  -7.67201760892087*^306, 
  5.333094706708313*^306, 
  4.446925629708386*^306, 
  -7.817378048373208*^306, 
  5.434139963604837*^306, 
  4.089540786133408*^306, 
  -7.189120986388672*^306, 
  4.9974159383854617*^306, 
  3.9615068570505863*^306, 
  -6.964046471993284*^306, 
  4.840958567909506*^306, 
  3.8743053780792307*^306, 
  -6.810752492228423*^306, 
  4.734398422491745*^306}, 
 {3.781304214412078*^306, 
  -6.647263080472186*^306, 
  4.620751066491604*^306, 
  3.98516673397331*^306, 
  -7.005638847914138*^306, 
  4.8698709207180616*^306, 
  3.9276657736932985*^306, 
  -6.904556261407554*^306, 
  4.79960478806323*^306, 
  3.6799284697010196*^306, 
  -6.469051752617422*^306, 
  4.4968699783991354*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.874115888489161*^306, 
  -6.810419383045777*^306, 
  4.7341668663471124*^306, 
  3.829920695457503*^306, 
  -6.732727386233149*^306, 
  4.680160371826918*^306, 
  3.662471097047468*^306, 
  -6.438362936763964*^306, 
  4.4755370814056626*^306, 
  3.6193421980869895*^306, 
  -6.362545408867447*^306, 
  4.42283359748372*^306, 
  3.527677039492444*^306, 
  -6.201404598728772*^306, 
  4.310818838734212*^306}, 
 {-6.647263080472186*^306, 
  1.1685414332070263*^307, 
  -8.12295076690035*^306, 
  -7.005638847914138*^306, 
  1.2315413367528236*^307, 
  -8.560885700381923*^306, 
  -6.904556261407554*^306, 
  1.213771739088534*^307, 
  -8.437362851407276*^306, 
  -6.469051752617422*^306, 
  1.1372131529894273*^307, 
  -7.905176650735032*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.810419383045777*^306, 
  1.1972231473708893*^307, 
  -8.322327652856341*^306, 
  -6.732727386233149*^306, 
  1.183565448524751*^307, 
  -8.227388087887848*^306, 
  -6.438362936763964*^306, 
  1.1318182780722336*^307, 
  -7.867674939541377*^306, 
  -6.362545408867447*^306, 
  1.1184900974905624*^307, 
  -7.775025974258095*^306, 
  -6.201404598728772*^306, 
  1.0901626925198218*^307, 
  -7.578112018627215*^306}, 
 {4.620751066491604*^306, 
  -8.12295076690035*^306, 
  5.646554523993312*^306, 
  4.8698709207180616*^306, 
  -8.560885700381923*^306, 
  5.950978809062406*^306, 
  4.79960478806323*^306, 
  -8.437362851407276*^306, 
  5.865113644824743*^306, 
  4.4968699783991354*^306, 
  -7.905176650735032*^306, 
  5.4951719222603755*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.7341668663471124*^306, 
  -8.322327652856341*^306, 
  5.7851485509277*^306, 
  4.680160371826918*^306, 
  -8.227388087887848*^306, 
  5.719152652951408*^306, 
  4.4755370814056626*^306, 
  -7.867674939541377*^306, 
  5.4691031372739043*^306, 
  4.42283359748372*^306, 
  -7.775025974258095*^306, 
  5.4046995173239537*^306, 
  4.310818838734212*^306, 
  -7.578112018627215*^306, 
  5.267817561626806*^306}, 
 {3.51759808243552*^306, 
  -6.183686511176122*^306, 
  4.2985023603634954*^306, 
  3.7732495312052806*^306, 
  -6.633103521952304*^306, 
  4.610908249329154*^306, 
  4.0207837877598504*^306, 
  -7.06825108783075*^306, 
  4.9133949351684666*^306, 
  3.571390908322127*^306, 
  -6.278250461928206*^306, 
  4.3642371554211796*^306, 
  3.874115888489161*^306, 
  -6.810419383045777*^306, 
  4.7341668663471124*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.557024609355578*^306, 
  -6.252995533123645*^306, 
  4.346681548279548*^306, 
  3.9061259995270014*^306, 
  -6.866690874901065*^306, 
  4.773283199318385*^306, 
  3.774323999670507*^306, 
  -6.634992360870052*^306, 
  4.6122212490311296*^306, 
  3.6997598931182865*^306, 
  -6.503913980367406*^306, 
  4.5211039637410505*^306}, 
 {-6.183686511176122*^306, 
  1.0870479791149493*^307, 
  -7.556460528212067*^306, 
  -6.633103521952304*^306, 
  1.1660522838223707*^307, 
  -8.105647796437825*^306, 
  -7.06825108783075*^306, 
  1.2425481219037526*^307, 
  -8.637397813125304*^306, 
  -6.278250461928206*^306, 
  1.1036716471124116*^307, 
  -7.67201760892087*^306, 
  -6.810419383045777*^306, 
  1.1972231473708893*^307, 
  -8.322327652856341*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.252995533123645*^306, 
  1.0992320107773431*^307, 
  -7.64115610384464*^306, 
  -6.866690874901065*^306, 
  1.2071152742425408*^307, 
  -8.391091375968692*^306, 
  -6.634992360870052*^306, 
  1.1663843282306214*^307, 
  -8.10795595625484*^306, 
  -6.503913980367406*^306, 
  1.1433416839481964*^307, 
  -7.947778268304451*^306}, 
 {4.2985023603634954*^306, 
  -7.556460528212067*^306, 
  5.252766833798561*^306, 
  4.610908249329154*^306, 
  -8.105647796437825*^306, 
  5.634526608406059*^306, 
  4.9133949351684666*^306, 
  -8.637397813125304*^306, 
  6.004165123832632*^306, 
  4.3642371554211796*^306, 
  -7.67201760892087*^306, 
  5.333094706708313*^306, 
  4.7341668663471124*^306, 
  -8.322327652856341*^306, 
  5.7851485509277*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.346681548279548*^306, 
  -7.64115610384464*^306, 
  5.31164176724012*^306, 
  4.773283199318385*^306, 
  -8.391091375968692*^306, 
  5.832948682058476*^306, 
  4.6122212490311296*^306, 
  -8.10795595625484*^306, 
  5.636131093110062*^306, 
  4.5211039637410505*^306, 
  -7.947778268304451*^306, 
  5.524785835149796*^306}, 
 {4.0378293703075546*^306, 
  -7.098216006051991*^306, 
  4.934224624944834*^306, 
  3.856803722207895*^306, 
  -6.779985829636917*^306, 
  4.713011411437522*^306, 
  3.6262148204805167*^306, 
  -6.374626988796509*^306, 
  4.4312319371712406*^306, 
  3.6390574568563934*^306, 
  -6.39720342745276*^306, 
  4.446925629708386*^306, 
  3.829920695457503*^306, 
  -6.732727386233149*^306, 
  4.680160371826918*^306, 
  3.557024609355578*^306, 
  -6.252995533123645*^306, 
  4.346681548279548*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.3705045411254564*^306, 
  -5.92510655804788*^306, 
  4.118754157272097*^306, 
  3.3643796587281805*^306, 
  -5.914339451694345*^306, 
  4.1112695553293383*^306, 
  3.276171753109707*^306, 
  -5.759276245674403*^306, 
  4.0034795572630436*^306}, 
 {-7.098216006051991*^306, 
  1.247815740780918*^307, 
  -8.674014921926125*^306, 
  -6.779985829636917*^306, 
  1.191873145770615*^307, 
  -8.285137872188832*^306, 
  -6.374626988796509*^306, 
  1.1206139530616148*^307, 
  -7.789789656357341*^306, 
  -6.39720342745276*^306, 
  1.1245827299348496*^307, 
  -7.817378048373208*^306, 
  -6.732727386233149*^306, 
  1.183565448524751*^307, 
  -8.227388087887848*^306, 
  -6.252995533123645*^306, 
  1.0992320107773431*^307, 
  -7.64115610384464*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -5.92510655804788*^306, 
  1.041591467860754*^307, 
  -7.24047600899865*^306, 
  -5.914339451694345*^306, 
  1.0396986873678598*^307, 
  -7.227318612675841*^306, 
  -5.759276245674403*^306, 
  1.012439681848351*^307, 
  -7.037831484964891*^306}, 
 {4.934224624944834*^306, 
  -8.674014921926125*^306, 
  6.029618989956918*^306, 
  4.713011411437522*^306, 
  -8.285137872188832*^306, 
  5.759296600041806*^306, 
  4.4312319371712406*^306, 
  -7.789789656357341*^306, 
  5.414962282461961*^306, 
  4.446925629708386*^306, 
  -7.817378048373208*^306, 
  5.434139963604837*^306, 
  4.680160371826918*^306, 
  -8.227388087887848*^306, 
  5.719152652951408*^306, 
  4.346681548279548*^306, 
  -7.64115610384464*^306, 
  5.31164176724012*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.118754157272097*^306, 
  -7.24047600899865*^306, 
  5.0331146571847644*^306, 
  4.1112695553293383*^306, 
  -7.227318612675841*^306, 
  5.023968478922393*^306, 
  4.0034795572630436*^306, 
  -7.037831484964891*^306, 
  4.892249177781899*^306}, 
 {3.356800284504563*^306, 
  -5.901015452462095*^306, 
  4.102007565407017*^306, 
  3.539871810893023*^306, 
  -6.222842136972033*^306, 
  4.325720840731321*^306, 
  3.7667170306425864*^306, 
  -6.621619851940232*^306, 
  4.602925538277533*^306, 
  3.346598331547328*^306, 
  -5.883081146890257*^306, 
  4.089540786133408*^306, 
  3.662471097047468*^306, 
  -6.438362936763964*^306, 
  4.4755370814056626*^306, 
  3.9061259995270014*^306, 
  -6.866690874901065*^306, 
  4.773283199318385*^306, 
  3.3705045411254564*^306, 
  -5.92510655804788*^306, 
  4.118754157272097*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  3.9560394849721805*^306, 
  -6.954435221878715*^306, 
  4.8342774431097386*^306, 
  3.920003545893777*^306, 
  -6.891086611498986*^306, 
  4.7902415511299526*^306}, 
 {-5.901015452462095*^306, 
  1.0373564233457479*^307, 
  -7.211036695069822*^306, 
  -6.222842136972033*^306, 
  1.0939312588244717*^307, 
  -7.604308675146666*^306, 
  -6.621619851940232*^306, 
  1.1640335365497068*^307, 
  -8.091614759832817*^306, 
  -5.883081146890257*^306, 
  1.0342037003554311*^307, 
  -7.189120986388672*^306, 
  -6.438362936763964*^306, 
  1.1318182780722336*^307, 
  -7.867674939541377*^306, 
  -6.866690874901065*^306, 
  1.2071152742425408*^307, 
  -8.391091375968692*^306, 
  -5.92510655804788*^306, 
  1.041591467860754*^307, 
  -7.24047600899865*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -6.954435221878715*^306, 
  1.2225401045421406*^307, 
  -8.498314905704879*^306, 
  -6.891086611498986*^306, 
  1.2114038707164825*^307, 
  -8.42090294877816*^306}, 
 {4.102007565407017*^306, 
  -7.211036695069822*^306, 
  5.012650333810375*^306, 
  4.325720840731321*^306, 
  -7.604308675146666*^306, 
  5.2860277974916044*^306, 
  4.602925538277533*^306, 
  -8.091614759832817*^306, 
  5.624771741166156*^306, 
  4.089540786133408*^306, 
  -7.189120986388672*^306, 
  4.9974159383854617*^306, 
  4.4755370814056626*^306, 
  -7.867674939541377*^306, 
  5.4691031372739043*^306, 
  4.773283199318385*^306, 
  -8.391091375968692*^306, 
  5.832948682058476*^306, 
  4.118754157272097*^306, 
  -7.24047600899865*^306, 
  5.0331146571847644*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.8342774431097386*^306, 
  -8.498314905704879*^306, 
  5.907483604685052*^306, 
  4.7902415511299526*^306, 
  -8.42090294877816*^306, 
  5.85367177593719*^306}, 
 {3.377816973501901*^306, 
  -5.93796129255433*^306, 
  4.1276899444466173*^306, 
  3.4701265213078897*^306, 
  -6.100234892961072*^306, 
  4.2404921463551987*^306, 
  3.6425108735207126*^306, 
  -6.403274287609083*^306, 
  4.45114570242136*^306, 
  3.241824187980187*^306, 
  -5.69889567626151*^306, 
  3.9615068570505863*^306, 
  3.6193421980869895*^306, 
  -6.362545408867447*^306, 
  4.42283359748372*^306, 
  3.774323999670507*^306, 
  -6.634992360870052*^306, 
  4.6122212490311296*^306, 
  3.3643796587281805*^306, 
  -5.914339451694345*^306, 
  4.1112695553293383*^306, 
  3.9560394849721805*^306, 
  -6.954435221878715*^306, 
  4.8342774431097386*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  4.062093416665989*^306, 
  -7.140870468744135*^306, 
  4.963875272375107*^306}, 
 {-5.93796129255433*^306, 
  1.0438512384914352*^307, 
  -7.256184485442771*^306, 
  -6.100234892961072*^306, 
  1.0723777799108683*^307, 
  -7.45448270997731*^306, 
  -6.403274287609083*^306, 
  1.125649943845596*^307, 
  -7.824796635175863*^306, 
  -5.69889567626151*^306, 
  1.001825208452996*^307, 
  -6.964046471993284*^306, 
  -6.362545408867447*^306, 
  1.1184900974905624*^307, 
  -7.775025974258095*^306, 
  -6.634992360870052*^306, 
  1.1663843282306214*^307, 
  -8.10795595625484*^306, 
  -5.914339451694345*^306, 
  1.0396986873678598*^307, 
  -7.227318612675841*^306, 
  -6.954435221878715*^306, 
  1.2225401045421406*^307, 
  -8.498314905704879*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  -7.140870468744135*^306, 
  1.2553140910588514*^307, 
  -8.726138645064861*^306}, 
 {4.1276899444466173*^306, 
  -7.256184485442771*^306, 
  5.044034182770469*^306, 
  4.2404921463551987*^306, 
  -7.45448270997731*^306, 
  5.181878393449171*^306, 
  4.45114570242136*^306, 
  -7.824796635175863*^306, 
  5.4392968894651854*^306, 
  3.9615068570505863*^306, 
  -6.964046471993284*^306, 
  4.840958567909506*^306, 
  4.42283359748372*^306, 
  -7.775025974258095*^306, 
  5.4046995173239537*^306, 
  4.6122212490311296*^306, 
  -8.10795595625484*^306, 
  5.636131093110062*^306, 
  4.1112695553293383*^306, 
  -7.227318612675841*^306, 
  5.023968478922393*^306, 
  4.8342774431097386*^306, 
  -8.498314905704879*^306, 
  5.907483604685052*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306, 
  4.963875272375107*^306, 
  -8.726138645064861*^306, 
  6.06585206007421*^306}, 
 {3.2897456023081654*^306, 
  -5.783138104313788*^306, 
  4.0200667913504564*^306, 
  3.3852889203129575*^306, 
  -5.951096442058326*^306, 
  4.1368206581470294*^306, 
  3.567133553182516*^306, 
  -6.270766335278956*^306, 
  4.359034670461939*^306, 
  3.170464507445024*^306, 
  -5.573450448118335*^306, 
  3.8743053780792307*^306, 
  3.527677039492444*^306, 
  -6.201404598728772*^306, 
  4.310818838734212*^306, 
  3.6997598931182865*^306, 
  -6.503913980367406*^306, 
  4.5211039637410505*^306, 
  3.276171753109707*^306, 
  -5.759276245674403*^306, 
  4.0034795572630436*^306, 
  3.920003545893777*^306, 
  -6.891086611498986*^306, 
  4.7902415511299526*^306, 
  4.062093416665989*^306, 
  -7.140870468744135*^306, 
  4.963875272375107*^306, 
  4.1715201480433983*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306}, 
 {-5.783138104313788*^306, 
  1.0166344263854468*^307, 
  -7.066990659287911*^306, 
  -5.951096442058326*^306, 
  1.0461603040784252*^307, 
  -7.272235628814887*^306, 
  -6.270766335278956*^306, 
  1.1023559910333393*^307, 
  -7.662872011466831*^306, 
  -5.573450448118335*^306, 
  9.797728321728929*^306, 
  -6.810752492228423*^306, 
  -6.201404598728772*^306, 
  1.0901626925198218*^307, 
  -7.578112018627215*^306, 
  -6.503913980367406*^306, 
  1.1433416839481964*^307, 
  -7.947778268304451*^306, 
  -5.759276245674403*^306, 
  1.012439681848351*^307, 
  -7.037831484964891*^306, 
  -6.891086611498986*^306, 
  1.2114038707164825*^307, 
  -8.42090294877816*^306, 
  -7.140870468744135*^306, 
  1.2553140910588514*^307, 
  -8.726138645064861*^306, 
  -7.333234856864358*^306, 
  1.2891303783143318*^307, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306}, 
 {4.0200667913504564*^306, 
  -7.066990659287911*^306, 
  4.912518766065072*^306, 
  4.1368206581470294*^306, 
  -7.272235628814887*^306, 
  5.0551919084324786*^306, 
  4.359034670461939*^306, 
  -7.662872011466831*^306, 
  5.326737273780226*^306, 
  3.8743053780792307*^306, 
  -6.810752492228423*^306, 
  4.734398422491745*^306, 
  4.310818838734212*^306, 
  -7.578112018627215*^306, 
  5.267817561626806*^306, 
  4.5211039637410505*^306, 
  -7.947778268304451*^306, 
  5.524785835149796*^306, 
  4.0034795572630436*^306, 
  -7.037831484964891*^306, 
  4.892249177781899*^306, 
  4.7902415511299526*^306, 
  -8.42090294877816*^306, 
  5.85367177593719*^306, 
  4.963875272375107*^306, 
  -8.726138645064861*^306, 
  6.06585206007421*^306, 
  5.097594660460223*^306, 
  -8.961207790830412*^306, 
  6.229257057416106*^306}}
```

If you we do Eigenvalues[mat], then you'll get non-real eigenvalues. How can that be?

```
Out[148]= {(...), -1.58298*10^291 + 
  6.14057*10^290 I, -1.58298*10^291 - 6.14057*10^290 I, 
 (...), 8.28201*10^289 + 3.31445*10^290 I, 
 8.28201*10^289 - 3.31445*10^290 I}
```

Comment: Also, Mathematica doesn't show any error message when computing this... i.e. it won't say that it's ill-conditioned.

Comment: With large exponents you just have to standardize a bit:  `10^306 Eigenvalues[m/10^306]` works fine.

Comment: @JimB So, it's a bug? By the way, thanks for the comment. How would I make that automatic. This matrix showed during a simulation.

Comment: @JimB I've tried dividing by the 'Max[mat]' , but it gives different values by something of the order of 10^-15 .

Comment: How about `Eigenvalues[Rationalize[m, 0]] // N` ?

Comment: @JimB From the simulations I'm doing, a discrepancy of 10^-15 still remains even with the Rationalize...

Comment: Discrepancies from what?  Sounds like a new question.  Your question above is only about getting imaginary numbers.  That is solved by scaling or using rational numbers.

Comment: How about `Eigenvalues[mat/Norm[mat]]*Norm[mat]`? Does should automatically adapt to the range of number and does not produce imaginary numbers, at least in my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say it's not a bug.

Be aware that `$MaxMachineNumber`  is around `10^308`. In your situation, when Mathematica is fed with machine-precision-numbers, the underlying hardware arithmetic will be called, and the intermediate results are very likely to overflow.

Luckily, you can renormalize your matrix, as suggested by JimB in the comments.

```
newMat = mat/10^305;

10^305 Eigenvalues@newMat
```

BTW, my experience tells me, even if the matrix itself is not ill-conditioned, the problem is practically ill-posed. 
Since one would expect that the *absolute error* of each entity is around `10^305*$MachineEpsilon~10^289`, which is enormous, you may probably go back and check whether the entities are trustworthy or check whether the large rescaling constant can be absorbed into a meaningful quantity.

Comment: thanks. I will ;)